# Websocket session.close in @OnOpen results in server freeze

Tags: glassfish, websocket, java-ee-7

I have a problem with a websocket in Java EE 7.
I tried to reject a connection in the @OnOpen annotated method. To close the connection I use session.close(). But after a few times the sever freeze.

Here is a short example. This example is based on the netbeans WebSocket Echo Sample Application. After a few message, the server freezes. No Exception is thrown.

Do I miss something? How do I reject a connection correctly?

I use Glassfish 4.0.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/echo")
public class EchoEndpoint {

  @OnMessage
  public String echo(String message) {
    return message;
  }

  @OnOpen
  public void onOpen(Session session) {
    try {
      session.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(EchoEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in TYRUS 1.0, see [TYRUS-212](https://java.net/jira/browse/TYRUS-212). I recommend using Tyrus 1.3.3 (latest stable version), it contains significant stability and performance improvements compared to Tyrus 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a bug in the websocket implementation you are using (Glassfish).

It is allowed per the WebSocket protocol, and the `javax.websocket` (JSR-356) API spec.

That behavior is well supported on other server side implementations of `javax.websocket` (like Eclipse Jetty 9.1 and Apache Tomcat 8.x)